# How to Correct Sprintf Input in R to Change Value in XPath?

Tags: r, for-loop, xpath, rselenium

There are a series of XPaths which correspond to a list of job titles on a webpage.

E.g. the XPath of one job title is `//*[@id="ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl04_Title"]`
The XPath of another job title is `//*[@id="ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl10_Title"]`

The pattern that changes in these are the digits (e.g. `04`) in the `ctl04` part of the XPath.

So, I'd like to write a for loop which iterates over the XPaths, going from 04 to 18 in steps of 1. I have this code:

```
for (i in seq(from = 04, to = 18, by = 1)) {
title_xpath <- sprintf('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl%g_Title"]', i)
}
```

I assumed through `sprintf`, the `'%g'` would be replaced with the values of i in the for loop (i.e. try 04, then 05, etc.), up to 18. But this doesn't happen.

Any ideas?

Edit: thanks for the suggestions so far. However, they don't work when I run the full code (pasted below):

```
title_list <- list()
item_count <- 1

for (i in seq(from = 1, to = 18, by = 1)) {
   
  title_xpath <- sprintf('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl%02d_Title"]', i)
    
  
  # Find the element on the website and transform it to text directly
  job_title <- driver$findElement(using = "xpath",
                                             value = title_xpath)$getElementText()[[1]]
  
  # Add the outcome to the list
  title_list[[item_count]] <- job_title
  item_count <- item_count + 1
  
}

print(title_list)
```

The part in this that doesn't work is related to the XPath. If I change the XPath from `ctl%02d` to `ctl04`, the job title at position ctl04 gets printed 18 times. What I want instead is for the code to print the job titles which correspond to `ctl04`, `ctl05`, etc., up to `ctl18`. Help appreciated.

Comment: it does work, `title_xpath` is overwritten on each iteration, however. if you need all of them `sprintf('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl%g_Title"]', 4:18)` would give you a vector. i'm not sure why you say it doesn't happen. if you need it padded with a 0, try `%02g`

Comment: @rawr when I run the code using e.g. `ctl04`, it works. But when I change it to `ctl%g`, R returns the error 'an element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters'

Comment: Do you have to use sprintf? Why not just use this xpath instead `//*[contains(@id,'ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ct')]`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need `%02d` :

```
title_xpath <- sprintf('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl%02d_Title"]', 4:18)
title_xpath

# [1] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl04_Title\"]"
# [2] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl05_Title\"]"
# [3] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl06_Title\"]"
# [4] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl07_Title\"]"
# [5] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl08_Title\"]"
# [6] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl09_Title\"]"
# [7] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl10_Title\"]"
# [8] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl11_Title\"]"
# [9] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl12_Title\"]"
#[10] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl13_Title\"]"
#[11] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl14_Title\"]"
#[12] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl15_Title\"]"
#[13] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl16_Title\"]"
#[14] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl17_Title\"]"
#[15] "//*[@id=\"ctl00_CPH1_vcyS_vsGrid_ctl00_ctl18_Title\"]"
```

Comment: thanks for the help, your suggestion works in that sense, but it doesn't help with the broader issue I'm having in the context of the full code. Can you identify the problem in the code I've pasted to achieve the objective I have in mind?